# S3 PUT directly to glacier

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

This [AWS post](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/s3-glacier-api-simplification/) from 2018 makes it sound like it should be possible to make S3 style PUT requests to create archives in glacier now:

I'm interpreting that to mean that you could use the s3 CLI or sdk interactions for uploading files, rather than the glacier specific api, or transitioning files. Is this correct?

I can't find any documentation on how this would actually work, as the link about S3 PUT to Glacier just goes to a list of storage classes. Tried experimenting some with `aws s3 cp`, but I'm not clear on what you would use for the bucket/s3 uri.

Does anyone know know if this usage is supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to these changes it was required to create an archive within Glacier and place files within that archive.  The link you referenced details how Glacier is now a storage class of S3.  You no longer need to move files into Glacier, you can simply upload them as storage class `GLACIER` or `DEEP_ARCHIVE`.  You can also change the storage type of existing files via the Permission tab or from the command line.

From the AWS CLI, you can use a command similar to this:

`aws s3 cp /etc/hosts s3://faketest/hosts --storage-class GLACIER`

You can see the storage class using `s3api`:

`aws s3api list-objects --bucket faketest`

To do this from the console, click on the Properties tab and select GLACIER

[image]

You can similarly set the storage class if you upload a file through the console.

For existing files you can change their storage class through the CLI using something similar to:

`aws s3api copy-object --copy-source faketest/temp.txt --bucket faketest --storage-class GLACIER --key temp.txt`

The above command copies an existing file from the bucket back to the same bucket with a change to storage class.  There may be alternative methods to this.

**References**

[Glacier FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/)
[S3 CLI cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)
[S3 Storage Classes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html)
[s3api copy-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/copy-object.html)

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful. We ended up pushing things to a regular s3 bucket and lifecycling to glacier, but this will be helpful later if we are bring up more instances which can go directly to glacier.